# What is modulus of complex number i?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was going through this theorem and the author had taken |i| to be 1. Is it defined? If yes, how?
Also, How do we solve modulus for square roots, in general?

Comment: To the extent $\sqrt{}$ is defined outside the non-negative real numbers, you have $|\sqrt{z}| = \sqrt{|z|}$.  Alternatively $|x+iy| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for real $x,y$

Answer (score 1):

Modulus of a complex number, $z = a + ib $ is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} $.

Put $a =0, b  =1$.

Answer (score 0):

$|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ when $z=x+iy$. So $|i|=|0+1i|=\sqrt{0^2+1^2}=1$.
Modulus is defined for every complex number in this way.
I don't understand question about modulus of square roots properly. If $z^2=w$ then $|z|^2=|w|$ and $|z|\ge 0$ so you will have unique modulus for square root of a complex number.

Comment: I meant if I wish to find the modulus of square root of 2. I guess by your definition, it is possible to find it out.

Comment: Yes. This is the definition. It's very standard. Its basically the distance from origin of the complex number if you view it as $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 0):

$|z|$ can usually be seen as the "distance" of the complex number $z$ from $0$ as seen in the complex plane. And $i$ is located exactly *one* unit "above" the zero. Hence $|i|=1$.